# Extension in System.Data.SQLite not loading: "The specified module could not be found"

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

My code:

```
//this is actually a hardcoded path but I shorted it for readability purposes
string loc = "libsqlitefunctions.so"; 
sqlLiteConnection.EnableExtensions(true);
sqlLiteConnection.LoadExtension(loc);
```

The error I get is that the "specified module could not be found." However, running this:

```
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sqlLiteConnection);
cmd.CommandText = @"select load_extension('" + loc + "');";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I get the same error, yet the command, when ran through SQLiteStudio, works:

```
//Same path as above, cut down for readability purposes
select load_extension('libsqlitefunctions.so'); 
select cos(radians(45));
```

This works fine and returns a result from the cos function that comes with the extension I'm trying to load. What could I be doing wrong? I'm starting to feel lost.

Comment: By hardcoded path do you mean an absolute path? Or is it just a longer relative path?

Comment: It's an absolute path.

Edit: I'm using absolute just for testing purposes at the moment.